# Change Xcode's environmental path variable

Tags: iphone, xcode, variables, path

I migrated from iphoneOS3.1.2.sdk to iphoneOS4.0.sdk and had to re-reference all frameworks.

The old OpenAL reference is getting stuck in the build script as I see the new one but the old one is also there:

---

Ld build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AweTrainGameEngine.app/AweTrainGameEngine normal i386
cd /Users/yuri/Desktop/AweTrainGameEngine
setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2 -arch i386 -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk -L/Users/yuri/Desktop/AweTrainGameEngine/build/Debug-iphonesimulator -L/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/usr/lib -F/Users/yuri/Desktop/AweTrainGameEngine/build/Debug-iphonesimulator **-F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS3.1.2.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework** -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/yuri/Desktop/AweTrainGameEngine -filelist /Users/yuri/Desktop/AweTrainGameEngine/build/AweTrainGameEngine.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AweTrainGameEngine.build/Objects-normal/i386/AweTrainGameEngine.LinkFileList -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -ObjC -all_load -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lxml2 -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework AVFoundation -framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework OpenAL -o /Users/yuri/Desktop/AweTrainGameEngine/build/Debug-iphonesimulator/AweTrainGameEngine.app/AweTrainGameEngine

---

I have searched thoroughly for manually cleaning up of the PATH environmental variable of Xcode but found nothing of value. I can't locate ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist on my snow leopard 10.6.3 system.

Please help!